# What files to delete in /home/user while installing new linux distro to get rid of old settings and configuration?

Tags: home-directory, hidden-files

I want to install Ubuntu in my laptop. I have `/home` as a separate partition. I want to keep all data stored in my `/home` but I don't want old configuration and old settings.

I want to install clean Ubuntu without formatting `/home`. But then my old configuration will remain unchanged.

What files should I remove from `/home`? There are lots of hidden config file in my `/home`.

[image: screenshot]

Also I am using Ubuntu with Arc them installed.

Comment: Linux Mint is off-topic here. Ask at [linux.se].

Comment: @Pilot6 But I am asking to remove old config file of Ubuntu mate.

Comment: @Pilot6: I'd argue that the question would be the same if the newly installed OS was Ubuntu. I'm going to edit the question to remove the reference to Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a full install, you can delete everything except your personal data.
the files required for desktop configuration will be reproduced when you install the system

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of the files beginning with a period, so you could just move them all into a directory to get them out of the way.  Then if you find that you really want something, like your firefox bookmarks stored under .mozilla, you can retrieve them.    A better solution might be to let /usr/home be a normal system created directory, and mount your "/home" directory under /home/user/data instead.  That would avoid potential problems if ever trying to dual boot two different Ubuntu releases with a common home directory.